# Converse of the Cauchy-Riemann condition

Tags: complex-analysis

The Cauchy-Riemann condition states that an analytic function satisfies:
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y};
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &= -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{split}
The converse of the statement requires additional conditions: the first partial derivatives of $u, v$ exist and are continuous.

My question is: When a function satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann condition, shouldn't it have already satisfied the above additional conditions? Otherwise, it wouldn't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann condition if its partial derivatives do not exist. Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: the partials may exist but not be continuous.

Comment: Doesn’t it mean we only need the second additional condition? But my textbook says we need both conditions.

Comment: It assumes that the function is continuous on a neighborhood of $z_0$, not only at the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x+iy)=\sqrt {|xy|}$. You can verify that the partial derivatives all exist at $0$ and satisfy the C-R equations but f is not differentiable at 0.

Answer (score 1):

The converse of the Cauchy-Riemman conditions require that $u,v$ be **differentiable**. This implies in particular that the partial derivatives exist, but does not require its continuity.

Comment: I believe the converse of the C-R statement requires $u,v$ to be continuous at the point under consideration.

Comment: Diffferentiability implies continuity. It Israel the partial derivatives that are not requiere to be continuous.

Comment: I am sorry. In the last comment, I meant the converse of C-R requires the partial derivative of $u, v$ to be continuous at the point under consideration (according to my textbook).

Comment: If the partial derivatives are continuous, then $u$ and $v$ are differentiable. But to carry on the proof of the converse of the Cauchy-Riemann conditions, differentiability is all that is needed.