# What does a function look like if its derivative is not continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

In a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2684155/converse-of-the-cauchy-riemann-condition/2684978#2684978) about the Cauchy-Riemann condition in complex analysis, I learned that a function can have derivatives in a region, but its derivatives might not be continuous.

My question is:

What does a function $y=f(x)$ look like at a point $x_0$ if $y'(x_0)$ exists but not continuous there? An example of such a function would be appreciated.

Comment: The derivative of a function that is analytic at $z_0$ is analytic at $z_0$, so in particular it is continuous there.

Comment: @idok I revised my question. Let me know if it is still incorrect. Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition you are using for "analytic"?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern I revised my question.

Comment: @TheOblivious you still say "What does a function $y=f(x)$ look like at a point $x_0∈\mathbb{D}$ if $y$ is **analytic** in $\mathbb{D}$ but $y′$ is not continuous at $x_0$?", which is I am asking what definition of analytic you are using.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Sorry, my bad. I corrected the question, again. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by region you mean an open set, then you're wrong: if $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then $f'$ is continuous (and indeed analytic too).

If what you want is an example of a function $f=u+vi$ such that at least one of the functions $u$ and $v$ is differentiable with a discontinuous derivative, you can take$$u(x,y)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$and $v(x,y)=0$. Then $u_x$ exists everywhere, but it is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: I revised my question. Could you help me answer it? Thank you.

Comment: @TheOblivious The new version changes nothing. If $D$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$ and $f$ is a function from $D$ into $\mathbb C$, then $f$ is differentiable if and only if it is analytic.

Comment: I think I restated basically what my textbook says. Here I am quoting from my textbook (it is about the Cauchy-Riemann condition, but the idea is the same): "Let $f=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be defined in some open set $G$ containing the point $z_0$. If the first partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ exist in $G$, are continuous at $z_0$, and satisfy the C-R equations at $z_0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $z_0.$"

Comment: Could you explain to me what I am missing in my question?

Comment: @TheOblivious It is possible that a function $f$ is differentiable at *some* points. For instance, if $f\colon\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is defined by $f(z)=|z|^2$, then $f$ is differentiable at $0$ (and only there). In this case, $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $v(x,y)=0$. Then the Cauchy-Riemann equations have one and only one solution which is $(0,0)$. Since the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are continuous, $f$ is differentiable there. I hope that this helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate your explanation a bit more? I still don't understand how this explanation fits into my question...

Comment: @TheOblivious Well, that's precisely the point: I don't know what your question is.

Comment: Ok. In your last comment, the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ at $(0,0)$ are continuous. Could you give me an example of a function whose partial derivatives at a point exist but are not continuous?

Comment: @TheOblivious Sure. Put$$u(x,y)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}$$and $v(x,y)=0$.

Comment: I am sorry but could you tell me what the derivative at $0$ is and why it is not continuous? I am not advanced enough to analyze this function...

Comment: @TheOblivious $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=\begin{cases}2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-\cos\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you! But what is$$
\lim_{x\to 0} u_x?
$$

Comment: @TheOblivious It doesn't exist. That's why $u_x$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you. Just a last question: could you show me how you found $u_x(x=0) = 0$?

Comment: @TheOblivious \begin{align}u_x(0,0)&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{u(x,0)}x\\&=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\\&=0.\end{align}

Comment: @TheOblivious It is *not* an indeterminate. In order to prove that that limit is $0$, you can use the squeeze theorem:$$-x\leqslant x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\leqslant x.$$

Comment: Thank you. I actually removed that comment as I recognized it was not in the indeterminate form. There are two things I hope you could do for me though:
$$
$$

1. Could you edit your answer so that I can accept it?
$$
$$
2. From our discussion, it seems like there is nothing wrong with my question (please read it again as I revised it several times). Is it correct?

Comment: @TheOblivious I've edited my answer.

Comment: In your example, the function is differentiable everywhere but its derivative is discontinuous at $x=0$. Thus, isn't it incorrect when you said in your answer: "if $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then $f'$ is continuous..."?

Comment: @TheOblivious I was talking about functions from $\mathbb C$ to itself and which are $\mathbb C$-differentiable. The function $u$ is from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb R$ and it is just $\mathbb R$-differentiable.

Comment: Ok. I guess this is where my confusion lies. According to your explanation, this is how I understand the continuity of a function's derivative:
$$$$
1. For $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, if $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D} \in C$ then $f'$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}$.
$$$$
2. However, for $g$, either from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g$ being analytic doesn't mean $g'$ being analytic.
$$$$
Is this correct?

Comment: @TheOblivious No, it is not. The derivative of an analytic function is always an analytic function. Do you know what “analytic” means?

Comment: How about the function in your example ($u(x,y)$)? It is analytic but its derivative is not (its derivative is not continuous at $x=0$). Am I still misunderstanding something?

Comment: @TheOblivious Yes. You are assuming the my function $u$ is analytic. It isn't.

Comment: But your function $u$ has derivatives everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Isn't it the definition of an analytic function? I am talking about $\mathbb{R}^2$ only.

Comment: @TheOblivious I think that I went far beyond providing an answer to your question. You still don't want to accept my answer? You have that right, but I'm out of here. Bye

Comment: I am sorry for keep bugging you. I am very confused and just trying to understand your explanation better. Could you please tell me what I am lacking in my understanding of analytic functions? Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: @TheOblivious 1. Go back to your notes and check the **definition** of a function being analytic. 2. Only after step 1. is accomplished, come back to this answer and see that it fully addresses your question.